# Change current window with window.location.reload

Tags: jquery

I'm wanting to change location of current window after location.reload. I can get the page to reload, but not change location.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {    
  location.reload (function() {    
  location.replace("https://stackoverflow.com");});
});
```

Comment: Can you explain that further? Why do you want to reload the page and change the URL? I don't think that there is any possibility to run something from the **current** scope after reloading

Comment: Sound like you want to do a redirect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant call a function inside the [reload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload) method. To achieve your scope try this code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){    
  window.location.reload();    
  window.location.replace("https://stackoverflow.com");
});
```